# Getting error when sending ERC20 multiple receivers

Tags: safe-core

I am getting the following error when trying to execute a tx, the thing is that the safe has the balance to the transfer, and in this error indicator it indicates another address that is not ours. Of course I have all the signatures already.[image: Image of the safe app showing that I have the balance and that the tx takes less than the actual balance, also it shows that I have all the signatures and the simulation failed error]

The transaction failed during the simulation throwing error ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance in the contract at 0x235ae97b28466db30469b89a9fe4cff0659f82cb. Full simulation report is available

Comment: The Error is clear. You don't have enough tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this safe does not have enough USDC to execute the transfer. If you believe this is not the case, please contact the Safe{Wallet} support on help.safe.global. A dedicated support service will help you there for all issues regarding our UI, while this stack exchange is aimed at developers having problems integrating our core technology (SDK or contracts) to their application.

Thanks!